# Why did Emilia give Subaru a fake name on the first time they met?

Tags: re-zero

On their first encounter on a timeline that was later reset, Emilia told Subaru her name was Satella. We then found out, after the first (or second?) reset, that that is the name of the Jealous Witch, and something of an insult to call someone else — Emilia reacted badly when Subaru called her out by that name after a reset and they hadn't yet met.

So why did Emilia tell Subaru that was her name that first time?

Comment: To gauge his reaction I would guess. She has many similarities to the Jealous Witch, after all, so telling that to anyone "local" would startle them at the least. Subaru has no such reaction.

Comment: In episode ... 11 I think (I would need to check), Subaru reflects on why someone would use the name of the Jealous Witch, and seems to come to the conclusion that perhaps she doesn't want to be part of the royal succession, and uses that name to drive people away.

Comment: It could be her way to test if Subaru's treatment to her would change if she gave him the name of the jealous witch, however Subaru doesn't know about it, he had not gave her a reaction she commonly get because of her resemblance to the witch..just my theory anyway..

Answer (score 6):

At about 11:00 in Episode 8.

> Beatrice explained the Jealous Witch to Subaru when talking about Subaru's "Witch Smell" in the library. Beatrice says only mad people will pretend to be the Jealous Witch. Suddenly, Subaru figures out the reason why Emilia pretended to be "Satella".
>
> That is because she didn't want someone else to get involved in the Throne Fight, with her special appearance, pretending to be the Jealous Witch is the fastest way to scare people away.
>
> But the plan actually failed because Subaru is a man from another world where the tales of the Jealous Witch doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, but that's _Subaru's take on it_, not necessarily the actual reason why she did it, which is what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 0):

As it was revealed in the princess selection episode, everyone in the palace and town already treat her wrong for her resemblance to Satella. Emilia seems to have not believed how clueless Subaru was, so she faked the name and winced after she said it thinking his reaction would be negative. At this point Puck looked at Emilia with disbelief and told her that she has poor taste as in attempting to gauge him. This shows Emilia was perceptive of the fact Subaru was not understanding of her country: Satella as the witch must be common knowledge to the citizens.

The question then is why she never told Subaru she lied, and I don't know that answer since he died and had to restart.  I just looked at the episode again and when she revealed to Subaru that she was half elf he had no reaction, which caused her and Puck to have an adverse reaction, since most people would have at least began to connect the dots.

Oh wait I am going to answer my own question she was prepared to tell him her real name if he had survived going in the loot house, which obviously he didn't: case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think either Emilia has some relation to Satella or puck definitely has some past with Satella ( ofcourse who am i kidding... I mean puck is her mother).
You might remember in episode one puck asked Emilia reason for introducing herself as Satella and later commented that she really have terrible taste.

As Satella name's connection is a secret to only Emilia and puck so It reveals her liking towards Subaru as she presented herself as the one everyone hated but in reality it is something which is very close to her. Also as Subaru was new to town her consciousness might have mixed up with the things she love when she saw Subaru.

And after resurrection when she got mad at Subaru fit calling her Satella it was normal reaction which she would give to anybody to fit in with people.

And the explanation for Emilia getting angry at Satella name might be that she doesn't get angry on people calling her witch Satella but the expression people  make on her while saying that makes her sad.

P.S.- I don't know if I am able to convey this to you guys. And I might be right or totally wrong. A 70-30 chance......